# Retrive Creation date of files in SVN from Command Line

Tags: svn

I want a SVN Command where in I get all the files in the SVN along with creation date. IS there a way to do it?

I want the command to run in Windows

Comment: There is no "simple" way to do it. You will need to enumerate all files in the repository, then find the first log entry for each of the files (paths) and grab the date/time of that revision.

Answer (score 1):

`svn log -v` for files with `A` status

Comment: svn log -v is providing all the info, M, A, R, etc. I want to get in one line like   DATE  --- FILENAME

Comment: Won't this also pick up files when they're renamed or moved?

Comment: @Sandeep540, what Lazy Badger has given you is a way to identify files when they've been added. You then need to check the log entries for those files to find the date they were added.